# WooCommerce PDF Product Vouchers- Display order_created_date?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the WooCommerce Plugin: WooCommerce PDF Product Vouchers by Skyverge.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that I want my voucher to be able to show the order_created_date.

Currently the plugin function only allows us to show the voucher expiration date.

This are the snippet that I found from them, and trying to customize it to make it happen:

```
/**
 * Add a custom voucher field.
 *
 * @param string[] $fields associative array of voucher fields
 * @return string[] updated fields
 */
function sv_wc_pdf_vouchers_voucher_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['order_date'] = array(
        'data_type' => 'property',
        'label'     => __( 'Order Date', 'my-plugin' ),
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'wc_pdf_product_vouchers_voucher_fields', 'sv_wc_pdf_vouchers_voucher_fields' );
```

```
/**
 * Return a custom value for a property field.
 *
 * @param mixed $value the field value
 * @return mixed the updated field value
 */
function sv_wc_pdf_vouchers_product_weight_value( $value, $voucher ) {

$order   = $voucher->get_order();
    return $order->get_date_created();
}
add_filter( 'wc_pdf_product_vouchers_get_product_weight', 'sv_wc_pdf_vouchers_product_weight_value', 10, 2 );
```

```
/**
 * Format a custom voucher field value for output.
 *
 * @param mixed $value_formatted the formatted field value
 * @return mixed the updated formatted value
 */
function sv_wc_pdf_vouchers_product_weight_value_formatted( $value_formatted ) {
    return wc_format_decimal( $value_formatted, 2 );
}
add_filter( 'wc_pdf_product_vouchers_get_product_weight_formatted', 'sv_wc_pdf_vouchers_product_weight_value_formatted' );
```

The second part of the code, where I tried

```
$order   = $voucher->get_order();
return $order->get_date_created();
```

But then nothing shows up on the voucher... meaning that it's just not getting the woocommerce order date...

I know I'm just not using the right variables, or just the code is wrong, I hope someone can help me out!

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a workaround way to achieve what I'm looking.

Basically I utilize the code provided by SkyVerge:

```
/**
 * Add a custom voucher field.
 *
 * @param string[] $fields associative array of voucher fields
 * @return string[] updated fields
 */
function sv_wc_pdf_vouchers_voucher_fields( $fields ) {

    $fields['inc_children'] = array(
        'data_type' => 'user_input',
        'type'      => 'number',
        'label'     => __( 'Order Date', 'my-plugin' ),
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'wc_pdf_product_vouchers_voucher_fields', 'sv_wc_pdf_vouchers_voucher_fields' );
```

This snippet will create an "user input" field in the backend of the wordpress customizer, and from the plugin, you can make it to appear at the front-end (because it's a user input field, front-end at product single page will pop up a field for user to enter information).

Then I hide this field by using standard CSS trick, and then use jQuery to insert value into this field:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var months = ["January",
              "February",
              "March",
              "April",
              "May",
              "June",
              "July",
              "August",
              "September",
              "October",
              "November",
              "December"]
        var years = new Date().getFullYear();
        var date = new Date().getDate();
jQuery("input#cer-month").val(months[new Date().getMonth()]+' '+date+', '+years);
    });
</script>
```

So in this way, the field will auto-prefill the current month, date, and year when the page load, so that I can print the information from this input onto my pdf voucher.

Hope this may help someone that stuck at the same situation as I did!